# Derive least squares solution

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-algebra

I have the equation
$$
R_{\text{emp}}(w) = \frac{1}{2N} \lVert \Phi w -y \rVert ^2 
= \frac{1}{2N}
\sum_{i=1}^N  \left( w^T \phi(x_i)- y_i \right)^2
$$
and am supposed to derive the least squares solution $\hat{w}=(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-2}\Phi^Ty$ (assume $\Phi^T\Phi$ is invertible).

I know that I have to take the gradient of the empirical risk and equate it to zero. The trouble  I am having is in differentiating the formula with the summation in it. Appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Try re-writing  $\|\Phi w-y\|^{2}$ as $(\Phi w-y)^T(\Phi w-y)$ and take derivatives with respect to $w$.

Comment: Many more threads available via search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=least+squares+derive+answers%3A1+score%3A3